# Question about conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

I want to know if the following sentences are correct or not.

> If you went to the party tomorrow, would you go with me?
>
> If you went to the party yesterday, why didn't you go with me?
>
> If you go to the party tomorrow, will you go with me?

Here's what I think the sentences mean:

The first one: "If you had the possibility to go to the party tomorrow, would you go with me?"

```
       Or maybe
```

"If you were to go to the party tomorrow, would you be willing to go with me?"

The second one: "If you did go to the party yesterday, why didn't you go with me?"

```
         Or maybe
```

"If you were at the party yesterday, why didn't we go together?"

The third one: "If you for any chance go to the party tomorrow, will you be willing to go with me?"

```
            Or maybe
```

"If you are going to the party tomorrow, would you like to go with me?"

I hope I got them right, please comment and let me know if I'm correct or not.

Comment: They seem correct to me. However, you haven't told us what you think they mean, so I don't know if they convey what you are trying to say.

Comment: @J.R. I'll edit my question

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is incorrect.  "If you went to the party tomorrow, would you go with me?"  The problem is that the sentence uses past tense, to refer to an event in the future.  The sentence could be corrected by bringing "went to" from past tense, to future tense, with "were to go".  Now it would read, "If you were to go to the party tomorrow, would you go with me?"

The second and third sentences are in correct form.

Comment: If so, how do you explain this example to be incorrect "if I went to Egypt, I could learn Arabic."  Found on http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/presentconditional.html

Comment: Manuel,  when you use IF + S. PAST,  and in the result clause you use COULD, WOULD or MIGHT, you are referring to an almost  impossible

Comment: activity to happen IN THE FUTURE.